# mPDF and dynamic centering

Tags: html, css, mpdf

I've just started using mPDF instead of FPDF and, well... I'm facing one serious difficult that concerns my project.

I want to set set DIV in which any content, usually dynamically generated (ie. MySQL data), has to be centered, independent of its size. Unfortunately, having gone through only a few solutions from StackOverflow, I can't do that.

I tried to do that with:

```
 margin-right:auto;
 margin-left:auto;
 width: 80%;
```

but the entire DIV is stretched and it just floats from corner to corner. Text can't get centered at any try... center tag just doesn't work, which is the worst flaw in mPDF's handling of HTML code.

Does anybody have any ideas on how to dynamically center any image or text, no matter what size or length it is?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you *don't need it to be vertically centered*...  What you have is very nearly what you need, or even I might say exactly what you need.  Here's some code and an example.

http://jsfiddle.net/X6zJ3/

**HTML**

```
<div class="box"><p>some dynamic content</p></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.box { width: 80%; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center; background: green; }
```

Play around with the width property in the CSS, and with the content of the paragraph tag in the HTML.  You'll see that it remains horizontally centered.

If you need it to also be vertically centered, then there is more that needs to be done.

Comment: @user3027309 The only difference is my addition of text-align: center.  Otherwise my code and your code is exactly the same.  You were nearly there.